# create an account form not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

when we click on create an account link then shows empty page means form is not showing,please see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: press f12 or right click on browser press inspect check if blocks are hidden by style

Comment: Kindly check the magento log file or console log on this page, is any error there?